# iOS inserting items at the top of a CollectionView without adjusting the scroll position

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift2

I'm trying to prepend items in a CollectionView, but it automatically jumps to a new position since the index path of the cells currently being viewed changes. All of the methods I have in my head seem really dirty and involve "close to the core" computations. It seems like such a common and simple issue, and I was curious if anyone has solved it already before I get nasty with it ;)

Comment: Chris, could you explain the use case?

Comment: You're right, the indexPath changes because you're adding items to the top of your array, therefore your count/position will be off in the later items. I doubt there is a straight forward way to accomplish this, the collectionView wasn't designed to handle this exact kind of situation. You may need to do some hack that adjusts the indexPath accordingly in the delegate method.

Comment: You can also try to use a custom layout.

Comment: @Darko I'm making an Instagram-like feed, and I want to make a feature that allows a user to jump to a specific date. If they jump down super far, I don't want to load every post in between the first one and the one they jumped to. So I'm making the post the jump to the new first index, and as the scroll back up, it will prepend posts to the top.

Comment: It's not common and not simple. :) What should happen it the collection view is currently on the very top of items and you add items?

Comment: Chris: you do not need to download all the items in-between when jumping down. You just need to know the count of items. Just create "nil" entries in the array and as soon as the user scrolls back you can dynamically load the items on demand.

Comment: With "nil" entries I mean any kind of marker for "currently not downloaded".

Comment: @Darko and due to the nature of the application and the current backend implementation, I won't be able to know the number of items in between the first on and the one the user jumps to. But I think I'm almost at a working solution. It's just pretty dirty. ;)

Comment: Change the backend. :) The user can not add posts in the past, can they?

Comment: I see, ok, it could be like Facebook, new posts on top.

Comment: @Darko bingo! So yeah I definitely need this functionality and changing the backend won't solve it. But I'm so close to solving it. Right now I have it working perfectly, the only problem is it halts any scrolling animation when it prepends items. So I'm trying to capture the current velocity of the scroll, and re-apply after it the prepending process. I told you, its getting dirty. hahaha

Comment: How about a "reverse" array? Fetching the first entry of the array returns the last. Or can the list grow on both sides? Then search for "endless scrolling", there are already solutions available.